# webservice enum

Tags: c#, web-services, enums, asmx

I have a web service in which I created an enum.. i have a webmethod which gets the value from the enum.

```
  [WebMethod(Description = "testing enum")]
public string getdesctest(class1.Myenum text)
{
    class1 dt = new class1();
    string valee =dt.getenumDesc(text);
    return valee;         
       }

 public class1
   { 
  public  Myenum{ 123  ,
      [Description("123")], 
          345  
      [Description("123")], }
```

i am consuming this webservice, where i call the getdesctest() webmethod, can someone tell me how should i instatiate it..

i tried something like

```
string djf= webservice1.getdesctest(webservice1.myenum.123);
```

but i am getting a object reference not set.. can some one help??

Comment: Your sample code wouldn't compile as is, not even close.

Comment: i figured out everything else.. can u just tell me how can i call an enum from the consuming website??

Comment: You figured out what? The code doesn't compile.

Comment: No broken class says , not even close.. i figured all my other mistakes, i just need to figure out.. how to pass enum to my webmethod!

Comment: Sorry guys !! My bad.. i had another class inside another class :( figured it out now thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception is something else -- more than likely, you've not set your `webservice1` variable to anything, although it is impossible to say for sure without seeing (more of) your code.

Comment: i figured out my answer yesterday @Rowland! u were right i dint set the variable :)

Comment: When you find the answer out yourself, you can add your solution as an answer to your own question (and accept it if the question is old enough); for example: http://superuser.com/a/404582/302